# How to use 3DS Max Python Package pymxs along with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, 3dsmax

I need to modify a python script developed for 3DS Max 2021. I am aware that python can be run from Script editor of 3DS Max. It is also possible to run with "3dsmax -U PythonHost demo.py".
But my issue is the following:
I need to run from a separate virtual environment. Kivy needs to installed there. Kivy UI should invoke a script that imports pymxs.
The problem:
The package pymxs gives error - it is not found. From documentation, I understand that there is no such package available for pip install.
I do not get this error if running the script from 3dsmax -U PythonHost command. Any idea how to do this? How do I set up environment so that it can have external packages while keeping 3dsmax happy?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to import pymxs into a script now running within 3dsmax's instance environment? then it won't work.

you need to add your external modules to the environment paths so that they can be ran from max, that way if one of your modules then tries and imports pymxs it will work.

Answer (score 0):

3DS Max has a utility EXE called 3dsmaxbatch.exe. Instead of running python myscript.py in command line, do it with '3dsmaxbatch.exe myscript.py.  In this, 'import  pymxs' will not give error.